# Kick out issue in Application

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, out

Ours is an application that has already been to production.
We have maintenance and enhancements for the same application.
When our QA onsite team was testing the application (several logins in the same application at a time), they faced kick out issue in some random scenario.
Randomly sometimes, few users are getting logged off and are being redirected to Login page (with session timeout message).Although, session timeout has not happened yet.

We are trying to analyse errorLog files and analyse the case.

Please help if you have any similar scenario and any sol. for the same.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the same scenario, but I once had an issue in which a report that was saved to PDF had to write a lot of physical files (graphics), and the creation of so many dynamical files was triggering an application pool restart. This only happened when my application was deployed to a shared server (hosted), which I'm not sure if yours is, but the fact that it did not happen when I deployed locally to a test server means that there are certain policies/settings that can be changed to control application pool restarts.

You can probably find out more about your issue if you log application shutdown occurrences as the following Scott Guthrie's blog post shows:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/14/433194.aspx

Comment: Thank u.The blog is really helpfull.

Comment: jaya, if the link or my answer helped in fixing the problem, you might want to mark as answer.